# Regex to find anything including a certain character, but only if before another character or end of line

Tags: regex

Consider the follow strings (they are URIs):

```
1) /apps/jackson/maybe
2) /notes/hereitis%there/hack
3) /things/halt_something/another?somevar=guay%2
4) apps/files_pdfvi%ewer/yeah?othervar=guay%3
```

I would like to match anything containing "%" character, but ONLY if it is located before the "?" character (separating the query args as if they are not there), or if there is no "?" (no query args), it may match also. Should not match anything if "%" only appears after a "?".

Tried so many things with regex101 but cannot isolate matching for lines 2 and 4 only...

- So Regex will need to match anything only for lines 2) and 4).
- Regex should not match anything from lines 1) and 3).

I tried for few hours without success and I am quite lost.. thanks for your help.

Comment: are you familiar with look aheads and look behinds?

Comment: also which language/regex engine are you using ?

Comment: tried look aheads and look behinds without success... everytime I tried to match end of the line or ?, I match against not desired lines.

This is for a location configuration in nginx, so I may be using Perl Regex, but maybe it doesn't matter with regex engine using if I could adapt the regex expression later just to fit.

Comment: So what was it you tried that worked best so far? What was the problem with that code? What did you expect to get?

Comment: tried like 200 ways to do it :D
for example:
^.*(?<=[%])[^?]*   (match line 3 which is incorrect)
^.*(?<=[%]).*(?=\?) (do not match line 2)
^.*(?<=[%]).*(?=\?|$).*(?=$)   (match line 3 which is incorrect)
etc... tried lots of combinations..

Comment: Just match only non-? characters before the `%`: [`^[^?]*%.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/KbnPic/1)

Comment: @Nick, looks good but you don't need the end-of-string anchor. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Nick your answer, when testing at regex101 for example, does match at line 1, which does not even contain a "%" character.

Desire to only match lines 2 and 4

Comment: feanorknd, by working harder to get a precise statement of the question the solution often falls out naturally. Here I would suggest, "match the entire string if it contains at least one percentage symbol and the first percentage symbol is not preceded in the string by a question mark".

Comment: feanorknd, there is nothing wrong with @Nick's answer. In order to test against multiple strings at regex101.com you need to replace `[^?]` with `[^?\n]`. That's because`[^?]` matches line terminators. Somehow the test strings at Nick's link got messed up. Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/L2sxyw/1) one. You'll see that if `\n` is removed from the character class the first match is not the first line but is the first two lines.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point about the `$`. I actually reordered the strings on regex101 deliberately so that I didn't need to put `\n` in the character class, as I didn't want to confuse matters. Doesn't look like that worked! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the results from the comments into an answer:

```
^[^?\n]*%.*$
```

You find a [regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/L2sxyw/1) with that regular expression and your test data prepared.

Comment: If, as in the examples, strings are not permitted to contain newlines, this regex is correct, though `$` is not needed. If the string may contain newlines then `^[^?]*%.*` can be used with the so-called "DOTALL" flag set, causing periods to match all characters, including line terminators.

Comment: Just to say, ^[^?\n]*%.*$ is working perfectly for me... at least working with NGINX locations/REGEX.

This is the complete line including the regex.. added some other restrictions, and it is working perfectly!!! CHEERS!!! Thanks so much!


location ~* "^(?!\/cool\/)[^?\n]*[~`<>;:%{}\[\]\|].*(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.jpeg)(?<!\.gif)(?<!\.png)(?<!\.zip)(?<!\.pdf)(?<!\.txt)(?<!\.flv)(?<!\.webp)(?<!\.webm)(?<!\.avi)(?<!\.mpeg)(?<!\.mp4)(?<!\.mp3)(?<!\.tiff)(?<!\.rar)(?<!\.7z)$" { set $restrule "29"; try_files /dev/null @restrictions; }